# Angular2 login service jwt token

Tags: angular, spring-boot, jwt

I try to implement the jwt token with angular2 front-end.
When I try receive the token with post method using Postman I receive authorization token but doing so in Angular returns null response object.
Here's snippet code of Angular service I use.

```
    return this.http.post(this.authUrl, { username: username, password: password })
                .map((response: Response) => {
                    console.log(username + ' ' + password);
                    // login successful if there's a jwt token in the response
                    let token = response.json() && response.json().token;
                    console.log(token);
                    if (token) {
                        // set token property
                        this.token = token;

                        // store username and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
                        localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify({ username: username, token: token }));

                        // return true to indicate successful login
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        // return false to indicate failed login
                        return false;
                    }
                });
```

The thing is that when I try to log the token is null same with response.
For the back-end portion of code I followed 
[this implementation of jwt token](https://auth0.com/blog/implementing-jwt-authentication-on-spring-boot/).

The only clue I have is that trying to invoke post method like that

```
this.http.post<any>(this.authUrl, { username: username, password: password }).subscribe();
```

I receive Subscriber object. Doing so with toPromise() instead of subscribe()
I got ZoneAwarePromise but I cannot locate token in both cases.

Comment: Is the token received from the server in the server's response body or headers? I don't know java but I was under the impression that the token was added as a header by the server in the link you provided

Comment: And are you using Http or HttpClient class?

Comment: I use httpClient class. Another problem this might be related is when I do http.post request and I try to add headers as 3rd argument I got error. private headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });

Comment: And where is the token from the server in the response? header or body?

Comment: It's in the header.

Comment: That's your problem then. You're only getting the body with your code

Comment: I changed to:  private headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }); Also added to post method {headers: this.headers} no errors during compilation but still my response is null. Also tried to change map to subscribe and still getting null value.

Comment: See my answer below

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. You need to retrieve the token from the authorization header, not from the body.

From the curl sample in the link you provided, you must call your service with type application/x-www-form-urlencoded

It might not work straight away (not sure what content type your backend returns). If it's not json you might need to modify it. But that should be enough to get you going.

```
    login(username: string, password: string): Observable<boolean>
    {
        const body = new HttpParams()
            .set('username', username)
            .set('password', password);

        return this.http.post(this.authUrl, body.toString(),
            {
                observe: 'response',//for 'special' headers in response
                headers: new HttpHeaders()
                    .set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
            })

            .map((response: any) => {

                let authHeader = response.headers.get('Authorization');
                //handle header here
                return true;

            });
    }
```

Edit:

If your back end is not on the same domain as the front, you need to 'expose' these headers, using the Access-Control-Expose-Headers header in your backend
So your server response should have that header

```
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Authorization
```

(see https://stackoverflow.com/a/48306230/1160794)

Comment: It didn't help. Although checking the chrome dev tools I clearly see Header of name Authorization with token in it. The problem I'm having is that it seems response inside the map method is null.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. What I needed to do is simply add **Access-Control-Expose-Headers** with string name of my header. Adding only **Access-Control-Allow-Headers** didn't work. Then on client side I could extract the header with the name of my header or any more header allowed by the back-end.

Answer (score 0):

When you are sending headers from angular, Api needs to allow origins of requests. Add this code in Spring Boot controller above the class like below. After that Api will be allowed to get headers.

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", maxAge = 3600)
@RestController
public class AuthenticationController {
    //services...
}
```