# HTTP request of 200 triggers "catch" operation in Angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, rest

I have a REST Login Operation that has been written in Java (for the server side). JWT is also used.

The client side is using the HTTP client under Angular 5 to access / execute the REST API.

What is taking place is that the Login REST functionality (using HTTP client) is executed. Afterwards, information is returned and the Return Code Status is 200 (meaning everything is OK).

According to the Chrome Browser "Network" tab, the RC comes back with a 200.

Even though this is the case, the "catch" statement (associated with the REST Login call) is *always* executed.

The code is listed below.

What am I doing wrong?

TIA

**Info from browser**

[image]

**console log**

```
admin-services.service.ts:208 TypeError: Cannot read property 'json' of null
    at MapSubscriber.eval [as project] (admin-services.service.ts:176)
    at MapSubscriber._next (map.js:79)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:91)
    at MapSubscriber._next (map.js:85)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:91)
    at FilterSubscriber._next (filter.js:90)
    at FilterSubscriber.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:91)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.notifyNext (mergeMap.js:151)
    at InnerSubscriber._next (InnerSubscriber.js:25)
    at InnerSubscriber.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:91)
(anonymous) @ admin-services.service.ts:208
CatchSubscriber.error @ catchError.js:105
MapSubscriber._next @ map.js:82
Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:91
MapSubscriber._next @ map.js:85
Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:91
FilterSubscriber._next @ filter.js:90
Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:91
MergeMapSubscriber.notifyNext @ mergeMap.js:151
InnerSubscriber._next @ InnerSubscriber.js:25
Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:91
onLoad @ http.js:2270
ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:425
onInvokeTask @ core.js:4744
ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:424
Zone.runTask @ zone.js:192
ZoneTask.invokeTask @ zone.js:499
invokeTask @ zone.js:1540
globalZoneAwareCallback @ zone.js:1566
XMLHttpRequest.send (async)
scheduleTask @ zone.js:2933
ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:411
onScheduleTask @ zone.js:301
ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:405
Zone.scheduleTask @ zone.js:236
Zone.scheduleMacroTask @ zone.js:259
(anonymous) @ zone.js:2966
proto.(anonymous function) @ zone.js:1366
(anonymous) @ http.js:2366
Observable._trySubscribe @ Observable.js:172
Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js:160
subscribeToResult @ subscribeToResult.js:23
MergeMapSubscriber._innerSub @ mergeMap.js:138
MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext @ mergeMap.js:135
MergeMapSubscriber._next @ mergeMap.js:118
Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:91
ScalarObservable._subscribe @ ScalarObservable.js:51
Observable._trySubscribe @ Observable.js:172
Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js:160
MergeMapOperator.call @ mergeMap.js:92
Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js:157
FilterOperator.call @ filter.js:61
Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js:157
MapOperator.call @ map.js:57
Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js:157
MapOperator.call @ map.js:57
Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js:157
CatchOperator.call @ catchError.js:80
Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js:157
AdminLoginComponent.onSubmit @ admin-login.component.ts:80
(anonymous) @ AdminLoginComponent.html:19
handleEvent @ core.js:13581
callWithDebugContext @ core.js:15090
debugHandleEvent @ core.js:14677
dispatchEvent @ core.js:9990
(anonymous) @ core.js:12332
schedulerFn @ core.js:4351
SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:239
SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:186
Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:127
Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:91
Subject.next @ Subject.js:56
EventEmitter.emit @ core.js:4319
NgForm.onSubmit @ forms.js:5751
(anonymous) @ AdminLoginComponent.html:19
handleEvent @ core.js:13581
callWithDebugContext @ core.js:15090
debugHandleEvent @ core.js:14677
dispatchEvent @ core.js:9990
(anonymous) @ core.js:10611
(anonymous) @ platform-browser.js:2628
ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:425
onInvokeTask @ core.js:4744
ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:424
Zone.runTask @ zone.js:192
ZoneTask.invokeTask @ zone.js:499
invokeTask @ zone.js:1540
globalZoneAwareCallback @ zone.js:1566
core.js:1427 ERROR Error: Unexpected Error Code: undefined
    at CatchSubscriber.eval [as selector] (admin-services.service.ts:216)
    at CatchSubscriber.error (catchError.js:105)
    at MapSubscriber._next (map.js:82)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:91)
    at MapSubscriber._next (map.js:85)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:91)
    at FilterSubscriber._next (filter.js:90)
    at FilterSubscriber.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:91)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.notifyNext (mergeMap.js:151)
at InnerSubscriber._next (InnerSubscriber.js:25)
```

**admin-services.service.ts**

```
[... snip ...]

  adminLogin(username, password): Observable<boolean> {
    let url = `${this._apiRoot}/login`;
    let tokenResp = {};

    return this.http.post(url, JSON.stringify({ username: username, password: password }))
      .map((response: Response) => {

        // login successful if there's a token in the response
        let token = response.json() && response.json().token;

        if (token) {

          let t = JWT(token);

          console.log("-- what is in the token --");
          console.log(t);

          //initiialize
          let setUser: User = ANONYMOUS_USER;

          // need to set the value here
          this.userLoggedIn.next(setUser);

          // store username and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
          // => SET BACK: localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(this.userLoggedIn));
          // => SET BACK: this.userLoggedIn = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));

          // return true to indicate successful login
          return true;
        } else {
          // throw an error that the token was "whack"
          return Observable.throw(
            new Error("APX: the token was not set properly"));
        }
        //return response.json();
      })
      .catch(e => {
        console.error(e);

        if (e.status === 401) {
          return Observable.throw(
            new Error("Error Code : 401 - Unauthorized Access To Server "));
        }

        return Observable.throw(
          new Error( "Unexpected Error Code: " + e.status ));
      });
  }
[... snip ...]
```

**UPDATE**
There is no response.

The login is using JWT. The information comes back as part of the header.

```
Authorization:Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJ0ZXJyZW5jZWRhcmJ5IiwiaWQiOjQ4LCJ0ZW5hbnRpZCI6MjU2LCJrZXlpZCI6MCwidXNlcm5hbWUiOiJ0ZXJyZW5jZWRhcmJ5IiwiZW1haWxhZGRyIjoidGVycmVuY2VAZGFyYnkuY29tIiwicm9sZSI6MSwiZmlyc3RuYW1lIjoidGVycmVuY2UgIiwibGFzdG5hbWUiOiJkYXJieSIsImV4cCI6MTUxODUwNTcwMX0.FNlvx-3WePXWEoqkDLfMw3GkkNcy_S-V3TcikBTfzOo
```

**UPDATE**

**code ran**

```
return this.http.post(url, JSON.stringify({ username: username, password: password }))
      .map((response: Response) => {

        console.log( "==>  looking for the answer - begin ");
        console.log( response );
        console.log( "==>  looking for the answer - end ");
```

**values produced**

```
NgForm {submitted: true, _directives: Array(2), ngSubmit: EventEmitter, form: FormGroup}control: (...)controls: (...)dirty: (...)disabled: (...)enabled: (...)errors: (...)form: FormGroup {validator: null, asyncValidator: null, _onCollectionChange: ƒ, pristine: false, touched: true, …}formDirective: (...)invalid: (...)ngSubmit: EventEmitter {_isScalar: false, observers: Array(1), closed: false, isStopped: false, hasError: false, …}path: (...)pending: (...)pristine: (...)status: (...)statusChanges: (...)submitted: truetouched: (...)untouched: (...)valid: (...)value: (...)valueChanges: (...)_directives: (2) [NgModel, NgModel]__proto__: ControlContainer
admin-login.component.ts:72  getting ready to go call the service 
admin-login.component.ts:76  values for id and password terrencedarby ----- 3333333333
admin-services.service.ts:175 ==>  looking for the answer - begin 
admin-services.service.ts:176 null
admin-services.service.ts:177 ==>  looking for the answer - end
```

Comment: can you add a console.log of the response itself?

Comment: Im 90% certain that this is a CORS issue. If you have access to your server,  allow CORS to happen and this error will likely go adios.

Answer (score 1):

the problem lies in the following code

```
    // login successful if there's a token in the response
    let token = response.json() && response.json().token;

    if (token) {
    ...
    }
```

the new angular 5 httpClient is returning JSON object by default therefor the .json() call on the response object is redundant. if you'll add a console.log of the response itself before trying to parse it as json you can see exactly what object is returned.

UPDATE:
Since the headers hold the token you can extract it like this,

```
let token = res.headers.get("Authorization");
```

Comment: Thanks for the information. I have made changes to the original post. Made changes as you have said. Was getting "null" back - see the changes in the entry above. New to Angular altogether. What does one do with the "null"?

Comment: the console log of response is 'null'?

Comment: yes, it is null - when looking at POSTMAN, saw that the "header" is set with the token but when clicking on the "body" tab, nothing is present and when clicking on the "cookies" tab, it says: "no cookie for you".

Comment: Thanks! The part about "let token = res.headers.get("Authorization");" helped me to get things up and going.

Comment: If the answer helped you feel free to mark it as the correct answer

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using Angular 5, you should consider using HttpClient instead of the old deprecated http.

To get the headers, you need 2 things

1. You need to specify 'observe': 'response' in the request options
   (see https://angular.io/guide/http#reading-the-full-response)
2. If your back end is not on the same domain as the front, you need to 'expose' these headers, using the Access-Control-Expose-Headers header in your backend

So your server response should have that header

```
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Authorization
```

(see https://stackoverflow.com/a/48306230/1160794)

Here is the modified code

```
adminLogin(username, password): Observable<boolean> {
let url = `${this._apiRoot}/login`;
let tokenResp = {};

//to post json with HttpClient
const headers = new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type':'application/json; charset=utf-8'})

return this.http.post(url, JSON.stringify({ username: username, password: password }), headers)
  .map((response: HttpResponse) => {

    // login successful if there's a token in the response
    let token = response.header.get('Authorization');

    if (token) {

      let t = JWT(token);

      console.log("-- what is in the token --");
      console.log(t);

      //initiialize
      let setUser: User = ANONYMOUS_USER;

      // need to set the value here
      this.userLoggedIn.next(setUser);

      // store username and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
      // => SET BACK: localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(this.userLoggedIn));
      // => SET BACK: this.userLoggedIn = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));

      // return true to indicate successful login
      return true;
    } else {
      // throw an error that the token was "whack"
      return Observable.throw(
        new Error("APX: the token was not set properly"));
    }
    //return response.json();
  })
  .catch(e => {
    console.error(e);

    if (e.status === 401) {
      return Observable.throw(
        new Error("Error Code : 401 - Unauthorized Access To Server "));
    }

    return Observable.throw(
      new Error( "Unexpected Error Code: " + e.status ));
  });
```

}

Comment: Thanks for the info! The code modification did not work for me - but - the hint about setting "Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Authorization" was key for me to get this working.

Comment: Glad to hear that Why did the code not work? You have to use and provide HttpClient class instead of Http

Answer (score 1):

Send the response as JSON,

`{ result: "Success",message:"1 row inserted or updated"}`

If the response is empty or a text angular is treating it as an error